# watchOS 3 SpriteKit TilemapNode Error

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, watchkit, watchos

I think that SpriteKit on watchOS doesn't support new Tile map Node element. I've done next steps (XCode 8.2.1, Swift 3):

1. Created new SpriteKit game
2. Added WatchOS game target
3. Created TileSet with default tiles (provided by XCode)
4. Placed Tilemap on GameScene.sks

When I run the application, I've got an exception on call of GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene"). GameScene is a child of SKScene.
If I delete tilemap node from .sks file everything runs correctly.

Error text:
'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeInt32ForKey:]: value (9223372036854775807) for key (_defaultTileGroupIndex) too large to fit in 32-bit integer'

What am I doing wrong? Please, help me to solve this problem!!!

Comment: It wasn't on the list of things missing from SK for watchOS during WWDC: ` On watchOS a few things are different. First, we don't have an SKView but now we have to use WKInterface SKScene to present our scene. We also don't have CIFilters but we can achieve the same effects with using an SKShader.
We don't have positional audio but we can play sounds just like any other platform using SKAction playSound. And finally, we don't have SKVideo Node but we can use WKInterface Movie to play a video. And this table summarizes the differences for SpriteKit.`

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/612/   but it seems pretty obvious that watchOS doesn't support tile maps :( but I haven't tried setting up a watch target yet.

Comment: Try making a tile node via CODE and see if that crashes it.